# cannot open or read metadata.rb!, while installing jetty

Tags: unix, chef-infra

I am trying to install Jetty cook book.
I used **knife configure site install jetty**.
I got the error cannot open or read metadata.rb!
I followed some posts where people say to execute 
**git branch -D chef-vendor-cube**. It does not fix the issue.

Please let me know where to setup the **hostname and portnumber** inorder to verify in browser
Please suggest me on this?

Comment: You mean `knife cookbook site install jetty`? And then I get a `Cookbook chef-sugar version 2.4.1 successfully installed` and `ERROR: IOError: Cannot open or read /Users/st/.chef/cookbooks/chef-sugar/metadata.rb!`. That's important information that you should add to your posting! What you mean about the hostname and port is unclear to me. The downloaded chef-sugar cookbook only contains a `metadata.json`. Seems that `knife cookbook install` is a bit limited. I haven't used it before, so I can't help..

Comment: The cookbook is downloaded from https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/chef-sugar. And as expected, the download does not contain a `metadata.rb`.

Comment: Stephenking,   Exactly I am facing same issue. And I am not sure how to test whether Jetty cookbook is working

Comment: See: https://github.com/sethvargo/stove/pull/59#issuecomment-61488239 and https://github.com/opscode/chef/pull/2345 and all the links here: https://github.com/sethvargo/stove/pull/59#issuecomment-61648364

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the chef-sugar cookbook. As a workaround (and general improvement) you can use Berkshelf to manage cookbook dependencies and downloads.

Comment: Add `jetty` as a dependency of your cookbook and then when you berks upload it will be sent to your server automatically.